# Gmail Desktop Notifications popping up, but not staying in Action Center

Tags: gmail, notifications

I have successfully turned on Desktop Notifications in Gmail for every new message:
[My Gmail settings with desktop notifications on for new emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPiiG.png)

So when a new email comes in, I get notified by popup:
[The Windows Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kOEA.png)

In the Windows "Notifications & actions" settings, chrome is set to show notification banners AND show notifications in action center:
[Image of all my Windows notification settings for Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80HYS.png)

When a new email comes in, the banner only shows for a few seconds and goes away (expected), BUT, it also vanishes from the action center. I'd like the notification to stay in the action center.

Any ideas?